# using jquery to vertically center container while respecting a media query

Tags: resize, media-queries, alignment

I need my jquery to vertically center a div on Document ready and **also** if there is a resize of browser but I'm having difficulty combining the 2 scripts. You can see below that I have to call it twice to get it to work in both instances. I'm sure there is a better way to write this but I am a little unsure of how to do it clean.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

if ($(window).width() >= 770){  

    var $el = $('#main');
    $el.css('position', 'absolute').css({
        left: ($(window).width() - $el.width()) / 2,
        top: ($(window).height() - $el.height()) / 2
    });
}


$(window).resize(function(){
    if ($(window).width() >= 770){  
        var $el = $('#main');
    $el.css('position', 'absolute').css({
        left: ($(window).width() - $el.width()) / 2,
        top: ($(window).height() - $el.height()) / 2
    });

    }   
});
```

Comment: Is there a reason you aren't just using CSS and no JavaScript?

Comment: @Conexion Yes, the reason I am not using css instead is that this whole container (#main) is part of a responsive website. There is a grid system involved with a height that is not a fixed number so the only css way to do that is using table-cell stuff which I don't really like doing. I figured the jquery would be easier.